# Ubuntu on MacBook M1

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

So I tried to follow Corellium tutorial on how to install Ubuntu on MacBook M1 https://corellium.com/blog/linux-m1.
As soon as I run this command `sudo dd if=ubuntu-20.10-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+raspi.img of=/dev/rYOURUSBDISK bs=1m`
It transfered data but then right after I get result

> the disk you attached was not readable by this computer

But before that I was using SSD (Samsung X5) just fine.
I would be really thankful if anyone can help with this.
Thank you all.